# How can I create a binding in Ninject that changes based on the requested controller?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, dependency-injection, ninject, asp.net-mvc-4

I have an ASP.NET MVC 3 app, and have run into the following situation.  On my page, I have a side bar, which can contain related links specific to that page, i.e., determined by controller type.  The links will be determined by the current page's content.

I have followed [Phil Haack's blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/11/18/aspnetmvc2-render-action.aspx) on rendering dynamic side bars such as this using `Html.Action` and a separate controller.  I like the separation of concerns this approach gives me: my controllers don't know anything about the side bar at all, which is the way it should be.

I now want to inject an instance of a derived type of `SideBar` into my `SideBarController`, an action on which will be called to render the side bar itself.  There is one derived type of `SideBar` per controller, and so I find myself wanting to write code similar to this:

```
kernel.Bind<SideBar>().ToMethod(_ => controllerName == "foo" 
                                         ? new FooSideBar(kernel.Get<UrlHelper>()) 
                                         : new BarSideBar(kernel.Get<UrlHelper>()));
```

but there's quite a lot that is wrong about that fragment of code, not least the fact that I can't get hold of the controller name in the lambda, and the question of what happens when a third type of controller comes along, and then a fourth, etc.

Note that I can't use `WhenInjectedInto<T>()`, as the `SideBar` instance will always be injected into the `SideBarController`.

For what it's worth, the instances of `SideBar` are currently being created via the Ninject Factory extension, so the relevant side bar bindings are as follows (I've hard-bound an implementation of SideBar just to prove the approach so far works):

```
kernel.Bind<ISideBarFactory>().ToFactory().InRequestScope();
kernel.Bind<SideBar>().To<FooSideBar>().InRequestScope();
```

Finally, I essentially have a one-to-one mapping between the derived types of `SideBar` and the controller types.  It feels a little bit like there might be a bit of duplication here, but also it represents the relationship between the components, so I think I'm ok with it.

This all makes me think that my approach to this part of the problem is wrong, and so I would welcome suggestions on how to achieve a clean solution with Ninject.

Comment: I don't see how specifying my bindings in XML would help resolve the problem I described.

Comment: You are 100% correct. Sorry, I completely misread the question. I think in my haste I actually read what I wanted to read instead of what was actually written. I am deleting the comment so that it doesn't mislead anyone in the future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll have a go at answering, but I'm not near a computer at the moment, and so it'll be a bit vague.

Fundamentally, you can pass another parameter to Html.Action, so if that parameter is either the Request or something gleaned from the Request (such as the controller name or Url parts) then you can use that to determine which sidebar to show. You may need to inject the factory into the sidebar controller, and use it to create the correct controller, or some other fiddling about, but once you know which sidebar is required, it becomes much easier.

Comment: Nice solution, thanks. Works well, and the factory was already injected.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is possible using ninject but it is using ModelBinding like so:

```
public interface ISidebar
    {
    }
    public class Sidebar1 : ISidebar
    {
    }
    public class Sidebar2 : ISidebar
    {
    }


 public class SidebarModelBinder : IModelBinder
    {
        public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
        {
            var controller = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["Controller"];
            var action = controllerContext.RouteData.Values["Action"];

            switch (controller.ToString())
            {
                case "Home":
                    return new Sidebar1();

                default:
                    return new Sidebar2();

            }

            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }


 public class TestController : Controller
    {
        public TestController()
        {
        }

        public string Index(ISidebar sidebar)
        {
            //Do something with it
            return "OK";
        }
    }

//Add to the Application_Start
ModelBinders.Binders.Add(typeof(ISidebar), new SidebarModelBinder());
```

EDIT: Took me a while, but managed to get it working using Ninject.

Please read it at: http://blog.voltje.be/2012/08/22/creating-a-dynamic-sidebar-with-asp-net-mvc-ninject/

Comment: This is a nice implementation, using MVC itself.  Unfortunately, in my implementation, I find the ModelBinder is only called when rendering the side bar, meaning that the `controller` variable is "SideBar" and the `action` variable is "Display".

Comment: The reason for this must be because I'm using `Html.Action()` as described above.

Comment: After a chat you indeed are doing something different. My method works fine, just not as how you are trying to achieve it. As said on twitter, I think you should adapt your logic to be able to achieve what you want...

Comment: I've let this as an answer btw, since it might solve some people's issues. At the end it looks better to use an extra parameter in the action method: public ActionResult Display(Sidebar sidebar, string someValueToIndicateWhichSidebarToRender). This seemed to be the TS' solution!

Comment: Updated my answer with a link to the Ninject solution! :)

Answer (score 0):

Suggestion:

- Don't inject sidebar.
- Instead inject [sidebar]ContentProvider.
- Bind a default implementation in global asax (per request), then unbind and rebind if needed in the controller.

Comment: Thanks Rory. I don't think I want my individual controllers to know about the side bar, it feels like a violation of SRP.  And I definitely don't want my controllers fiddling with DI bindings; I prefer to follow the [composition root](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2011/07/28/CompositionRoot.aspx) pattern.